# compile C++ code in Qt for use in C#.Net

Tags: c#, qt4, c++-cli

I have C++ code that is written with the Qt library.
I compile it with `\clr` and when I add a 'DLL' file to C# reference, I have no class and namespace that declare in it 'dll'.

Where is problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you resolve your problem.
You need to make a C++/CLI class in order to use it in your C# code. In the code of this class  you can make unmanaged calls but you need to return managed type. You can find information about C++/CLI and managed/unmanaged context on msdn.